# tkinter validate entry box

Tags: python, regex, tkinter

I have coded an app with python and tkinter. I have an entry box and I want that when the user enters a data it matches with the regex.
it must match interactively. That is to say when the user enters a value which does not correspond the value must be
not blocked. That's why I use focusin in the code. What I don't understand is that my entry is invalid even when the value matches the
not regex
In addition, the entry allows you to enter any value and not block it

Here is a working example

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

class FocusOutValidationDemo() :
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.errormsg = tk.Label( text = '', fg = 'red' )
        self.errormsg.pack()
        tk.Label( text = 'Enter Email Address' ).pack()
        vcmd = (self.master.register( self.validate_email ), '%P')
        invcmd = (self.master.register( self.invalid_email ), '%P')
        self.emailentry = tk.Entry( self.master, validate = "focusin",validatecommand = vcmd,invalidcommand = invcmd)
        self.emailentry.pack()
        tk.mainloop()

    def validate_email(self, P):
        self.errormsg.config( text = '' )
        x = re.match( r"#\d+\s[A-Z]\d+(?:[,-][A-Z]\d+)*(?:;#\d+\s[A-Z]\d+(?:[,-][A-Z]\d+)*)*", P )
        return (x != None)

    def invalid_email(self, P):
        self.errormsg.config( text = 'Invalid' )
        self.emailentry.focus_set()

app = FocusOutValidationDemo()
```

Comment: `validate = "focusin"` will validate only when the entry receives focus. Not when there is a key press or any other event occuring, ``validate = "key"`` is what you might want.

Comment: yes i already try it. But when I use this option I can't press any key. The message stuck on invalid

Comment: Its ok to enter any characters as long as they are recognized as valid or invalid

Comment: Can you tell us what your regex is trying to match? also, can you give us an example of valid input?

Comment: It is the folling of this subject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68063592/regex-python-conditions/68090157?noredirect=1#comment120355715_68090157 . I want to match #number A4-Q78,A4,B5587 for example

Comment: You should more likely `return True` and `False`.

Comment: Can you  give an example of a valid input

Comment: @CoolCloud: _"You should more likely return True and False"_ - they _are_ returning True or False. `(x != None)` will always return either True or False.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ah yea, I missed to understand that expression, thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `validate` if you don't want the entry to refuse the user's input, instead set a control variable to the `Entry` and use `trace` method to call a function to validate the entry.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import re

class FocusOutValidationDemo() :
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.errormsg = tk.Label( text = '', fg = 'red' )
        self.errormsg.pack()
        tk.Label( text = 'Enter Email Address' ).pack()

        self.var = tk.StringVar()

        self.var.trace('w', self.validate_email)

        emailentry = tk.Entry( self.master, textvariable=self.var)
        emailentry.pack()
        self.master.mainloop()

    def validate_email(self, *p):

        self.errormsg.config(text='')
        x = re.match( r"#\d+\s[A-Z]\d+(?:[,-][A-Z]\d+)*(?:;#\d+\s[A-Z]\d+(?:[,-][A-Z]\d+)*)*", self.var.get())
        if x is None:
            self.errormsg.config(text='Invalid')

app = FocusOutValidationDemo()
```

Comment: Instead of `tk.mainloop()`, it is better to use `self.master.mainloop()`. It's just best practises, doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: @TheLizzard thank you. didn't notice that.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not really what I want...because with this code the entry #15 A1, sdksdlksd is valid but in fact it is not follow the regex expression...

Comment: @Béa I didn't make any changes to the regex expression, It must be a problem with your regex.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem with regex but with re.match? because even if a part matches it displays true while I want all the users input matches

Comment: @Béa yes, instead try `re.fullmatch`

Comment: Super ! Is there any way to match when a key is pressed?

Comment: @Béa I don't understand what you mean. It does the matching when the key is pressed/string is changed.